# c# simple ui-automation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ui-automation

I'm trying to create a simple ui-automation program which moves the mouse cursor to a pre-defined place and then "clicks" a  button/checkbox/whatever-there-is. If there's an editbox I need to fill, I'd click it and then use SendKeys to add the required data. And if I'd do that - the later mouse moves are not performed. The code is:

```
mouseMove(pointA);
click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
SendKeys.Send("12345");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
mouseMove(pointB);
click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

So the mouseMove(pointB) is not executed.

I'm using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) because the software I'm trying to automate is quite unresponsive, so it "hangs" occasionally.

And it using weird 3rd party controls, so I cannot think of any other quick method to automate it - Microsoft's UI Automation does not recognize those controls :[

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that if you set a breakpoint on `mouseMove(pointB)` it is never hit or that the move/click does not happen in target application?

Comment: did you try giving focus to main form again? Or something like sending TAB to leave the active editbox?

Comment: @mikez - my program hits mouseMove(pointB) but it does not execute (the mouse does not move)
@ aliassce - TAB is not OK since it will now be sent to the editbox, so it would only add a TAB to the end of the text in the editbox

Comment: I'm assuming you are seeing the mouse actually move with `mouseMove(pointA)`? There are definitely automation mechanisms that can cause low-level input to be simulated without actually causing a perceived mouse move. What is the content of `mouseMove` and `click`?

Comment: @mikez there was a problem with SendKeys.Send, SendKey.SendWait fixes the problem. Thanks.